# Is there any way to change the output filename for qlmanage?

Tags: mac, command-line

Is there any way to specify the output filename and directory that qlmanage uses?

We are using `qlmanage` to convert word documents to HTML, and it writes `Preview.html` to its temp directory.  You can specify the output directory with `-o`, so right now we create a new directory for each file we write, which works fine, but... not optimal.

No mention of such a facility in the command line options, but i thought i'd ask in case there is some undocumented trick.

thanks,

ian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `textutil` to convert Word documents to HTML and specify the output filename; it uses a different converter, though, which may not be acceptable for your uses.

With regard to `qlmanage`, you're abusing Quick Look here already.  The output is a directory, not a file, which is only designed for Quick Look to consume.  That `Preview.html` is a fixed filename is by design; otherwise the Quick Look displayer wouldn't know where to start.  That you're able to extract the HTML output yourself is a nice side effect, nothing more.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, that is what i expected, but thought i'd ask.  The quality of the HTML that qlmanage creates is pretty excellent, do you know if textutil uses the same libraries?

Comment: Nope (I addressed this in my the first sentence of my response).  Apple has 3 different Office importers/exporters: the doc/docx I/O in Cocoa Text (which is what textutil uses), the iWork importers/exporters (*Compatibility.framework, which you'll find in the bundles of each iWork app), and the Quick Look/iOS previewers (the private OfficeImport.framework).  The latter two share quite a bit of code, and tend to be more robust/capable because they support the iWork feature set rather than just that of Cocoa Text.